# How do I get my (if "input" in list) to check every letter of the input and not just the first letter of input?

Tags: python, list, input

How do I get my (if "input" in list) to check every letter of the input and not just the first letter of input?

This is my code now:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæø˚a ?"

my_list=list(alphabet)
n= input()



def textis():
for word in n.split():
    if word in my_list:
      print(word)
    else:
        x=word.replace(n,"?")
        print (x)



textis()
```

but it only checks the first letter of the input. I want it to check every letter of input and change the ones that dont are in list to "?", and print the input again with the changes "?" in the sentence. So if input is, hello My name Is, output should be hello ?y name ?s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the problems:

- You need to pass in arguments in a function.
- You need to check every letter in the word instead of checking and changing the entire word.

What I did was make a new variable and made changes to that variable and then returned this variable.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæø˚a ?"

my_list = list(alphabet)
n = input()

def textis(n, my_list):
  new = ''
  for letter in n:
    if letter in my_list:
      new += letter
    else:
      new += "?"
  return new

print(textis(n, my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function will work as is with a slight modification. when you `n.split()` you are generating a list of words, `n.split() == ['hello', 'My', 'name', 'Is']` so when you iterate `for word in n.split(): if word in my_list` you are comparing words like `name` vs individual letters in `my_list`, you will never get a match. instead you have to use another level of nesting, `for i in word`, then it will work! (Also there is no need to create a list out of `alphabet` for this case, you can use it as is)

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæø˚a ?"

n= input()

def textis():
    for word in n.split():
        for i in word:
            if i in alphabet:
                pass
            else:
                word = word.replace(i,"?")
        print(word) 
textis()
```

All this being your program is still returning all words on separate lines and a little over doing for the task, instead something like this would do the trick.

```
s = input('Enter a word: ')
for i in s:
    if i not in alphabet:
        s = s.replace(i, '?')
# hello ?y name ?is
```